# SQL expression to fetch count of an object in a json file using AWS S3-select

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3-select

I have a json file in S3 with the following strucure

```
   {
  status: "Success",
  created_at: "19 AUG 2019",
  employees:[
     {"name":"name1", "id":"1"},
     {"name":"name2", "id":"2"},
     {"name":"name3", "id":"3"}
  ],
  contacts: [] 
}
```

The following SQL functions works fine to find number of contacts

```
SELECT count(*) FROM S3Object[*].contacts[*]
```

But sometimes, the json file doesn't have that `contacs` key itself like,

```
       {
  status: "Success",
  created_at: "19 AUG 2019",
  employees:[
     {"name":"name1", "id":"1"},
     {"name":"name2", "id":"2"},
     {"name":"name3", "id":"3"}
  ] 
}
```

In this case the above sql returns contacts count as 1 but I am expecting it to return "zero".

How to re-write a sql dynamically to handle both the file content?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`SELECT count(*) FROM S3Object[*].contacts[*] as item WHERE item IS NOT MISSING`

## Explanation

All the things refer to [SELECT Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html).

Consider this example:

```
{
  {
    status: "Success",
    created_at: "19 AUG 2019",
    employees:[
      {"name":"name1", "id":"1"},
      {"name":"name2", "id":"2"},
      {"name":"name3", "id":"3"}
    ],
    contacts: [
      {"a": "123"},
      {"b": "456"}
    ]
  },
  {
    status: "Success",
    created_at: "19 AUG 2019",
    employees:[
      {"name":"name1", "id":"1"},
      {"name":"name2", "id":"2"},
      {"name":"name3", "id":"3"}
    ]
  }
}
```

**If you run `SELECT * FROM S3Object[*].contacts[*]`**, the result is

```
{"a": "123"}
{"b": "456"}
{}
```

Since the second object has no `contacts`, so refer to [SELECT Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html),

> Amazon S3 Select emitted MISSING, which was then changed to an empty record during output serialization and returned.

So `SELECT count(*) FROM S3Object[*].contacts[*]` returns the count of the items, which is `3`.

**If you run `SELECT * FROM S3Object[*].contacts[*] as item WHERE item IS NOT MISSING`**, the result is

```
{"a": "123"}
{"b": "456"}
```

All the **MISSING item** will be dropped. So `SELECT count(*) FROM S3Object[*].contacts[*] as item WHERE item IS NOT MISSING` will return the count of the items, which is `2`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit on how this solves the issue?